# what's the best way to limit async send speed based on response handling speed in netty 4?

Tags: multithreading, performance, netty, blockingqueue, network-traffic

I'm writing a RPC client, which uses netty4 to do the networking.  The client put requests to a map, and after receiving responses the requests' callback is triggered in channel handler and the requests are removed.

During benchmark test, my sending thread seemed to be sending too fast as the response latency increased to ~1 secs.

So what's the best way to control the speed of the sending thread based on the channel handler speed?  Do I have to add another blocking queue so that if there are too many requests in the map, the sender got blocked against the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting AUTO_READ option to false for Server Bootstrap. This will control what amount of data you read on one channel before another channel consumes it.

Comment: I think my question is unrelated to AUTO_READ as I'm focused on the client side and I don't see why reading data on my own makes it better.